# How to set that all Lable foreground is White in Window?

Tags: c#, wpf

Follow method is invalid,I dont want to set color by ergodic. How to set by style:

```
Style styleLable = new System.Windows.Style(typeof(Label));
styleLable.Setters.Add(new Setter(Label.ForegroundProperty, "White"));
this.Resources.Add("", styleLable);
this.UpdateLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="LabelBase">
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>

    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Grid>
    <Border x:Name="Rectangle_MouseOver"BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}" CornerRadius="4" Height="Auto">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" Margin="4,0,4,0"/>
    </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger/>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

I recommend using `TextBlock` instead of `Label`. It will be a lot easier:

```
<StackPanel TextBlock.Foreground="White">
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" />
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" />
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" />
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" />
    <TextBlock Text="Some Text" />
</StackPanel>
```

With `Label`, you can do it like following:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Label Content="Some Text" />
    <Label Content="Some Text" />
    <Label Content="Some Text" />
    <Label Content="Some Text" />
    <Label Content="Some Text" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, then i got the answer.
here is the answer.

1. add this tag to your .xaml page.

   ```
   "<Grid Name="myGrid1">"
   ```
2. add that control to your grid and set Foreground using Brushes Class.

   ```
   Label myLabel = new Label();
   myLabel.Content = "New Element"; 
   myGrid1.Children.Add(newLabel);
   newLabel.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
   ```